# Standard regex to prevent SPARQL injection?

Tags: escaping, sparql, code-injection

I am developing a RESTful API in scala that sends SPARQL-queries to a triplestore. I read an [article](http://www.morelab.deusto.es/code_injection/) about the threat of SPARQL-injections when user defined params (URL params in a HTTP get request) are directly put in the SPARQL (e.g. in a fulltext search).

I saw some Jena specific solutions (using its Java API) that are not useful for me.

Is there some kind of standard regex search and replace pattern to escape malicious characters in a string that should be integrated in a SPARQL-query?

Comment: I don't really see where it would be any different from any other kind of sanitization issue.  You'd need to escape everything but legal characters.  The other things that could help is using a **values** block, because then you can limit the number of places where the injected things can appear.

Comment: Thanks. What would be illegal characters then? A fullstop for example could be part of a SPARQL query (at the end of a statement) but also part of a search string that would be put inside quotes in the SPARQL query. So I guess it would be a good idea to escape quotes in the string passed in order to prevent that they could be injected from the outside to end my SPARQL statement and add some statements I am not aware about.

Comment: I general, it can be said that the sanitization issue depends on what characters are considered to be metacharacters.

Comment: Perhaps "illegal characters" wasn't the best phrase to use.  I guess I'd say:  only let users provide values for variables, and then safely substitute those values into variables in your queries.  If someone submits a string like "?s ?p ?o", it's fine that that is a string, and when it gets put into the query, it should remain a string.

Comment: Exactly. And that practically means that the delimiters I use in my SPARQL for string values must be escaped if they are part of that string. So if I use single quotes as delimiters the string must not contain unescaped single quotes. See <http://www.morelab.deusto.es/code_injection/>

Comment: Yes.  Probably the best way to approach this problem is to write a general value writer that writes RDF terms safely.  That said, there may already be such libraries out there.  After all, the SPARQL syntax is so close to Turtle that most Turtle (or N-Triples) serializers would print values for you in a SPARQL-safe manner.

Comment: True but you can do some particular devious things if you are minded to which is what the ARQ implementation defends against.  For example [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-dev/201303.mbox/%3c5154A7F0.4010700@apache.org%3e)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am developing in scala and found out that escaping double quotes is a pain since they are also scala string delimiters (ending up in a series of backslashes). So I will look if I find a Turtle serializer to bes used in scala (incl. Java libs) as proposed above.

Comment: Does someone know [banana-rdf](https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf)?

Answer (score 0):

If the user input goes into a string literal within the query:

1. Use the triple-quote form: `"""..."""` or `'''...'''`, and
2. Prepend any backslash, single quote or double quote in the user input with a backslash

ES6 example:

```js
const escapeForTurtle: s => s.replace(/(["'\\])/g, '\\$1')

const query = `SELECT * { ?x :name """${escapeForTurtle(name)}""" }`
```

This is enough to prevent injection and syntax errors from unusual user input.

Depending on the triple store, some extra work might be required if you want to make sure that absolutely every possible user input arrives in the store without any lost characters or extra backslashes. The input `\\u0022` is a good test case. If that goes through without modification, you should be safe and done.

Comment: Can an attacker not add `"""` to their input to end the string?

Comment: @Jeroen But `"""` becomes `\"\"\"` in step 2, so it doesn't end the string. (I reworded the answer slightly to make clearer that steps 1 _and_ 2 must be done; it's not 1 _or_ 2.)